# Многопоточность в Java. Код их з книги HeadFirst Java

Tags: java, многопоточность

```
public class VerySImpleChatServer {
ArrayList clientOutputStreams;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new VerySImpleChatServer().go();
}

public void go() {
    clientOutputStreams = new ArrayList();
    try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000);

        while (true) {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            clientOutputStreams.add(writer);

            Thread t = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket));
            t.start();
            System.out.println("got a connection");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void tellEveryone(String message) {
    Iterator it = clientOutputStreams.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        try {
            PrintWriter writer = (PrintWriter) it.next();
            writer.println(message);
            writer.flush();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
    BufferedReader reader;
    Socket sock;

    public ClientHandler(Socket clietSoket) {
        try {
            sock = clietSoket;
            InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
            reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void run() {
        String message;
        try {
            outer:
            while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (message.equals("")) {
                    continue outer;
                }
                System.out.println("read " + message);
                tellEveryone(message);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

  }
}
```

Здравствуйте! Данный пример взят из книги *Head First Java*.

У меня следующий вопрос. При подключению клиента к серверу для каждого отдельного клиента создается собственный поток, или я не так понимаю? Я об участке кода приведенном ниже.

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000);

    while (true) {
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        clientOutputStreams.add(writer);

        Thread t = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket));
        t.start();
        System.out.println("got a connection");
```

Comment: Вот [этот](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JIqsvauBLQQ&t=420s) видос прояснит сутуацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, все верно. Для каждого подключающегося клиента создается поток. Причем нужно понимать, что метод accept() (на этом моменте сервер ожидает подключение очередного клиентка) выполняется только при подключении очередного клиента к серверу.